# I wanna create a trigger that queries the latest task (based on created/modified date) on Account

Tags: apex, trigger

I wanna create a trigger that queries the latest task (based on created/modified date) on Account.
It works fine on AfterInsert,but I wanna have After Update functionality as well.
Can anyone help

My code is as follows:

Trigger code:

```
trigger LatestCreatedDate on Task (after insert,after update) {

        TriggerHandler objTriggerHandler = new TriggerHandler();
        if( trigger.isInsert){
            objTriggerHandler.onAfterInsert(trigger.new);
        } 
        if(trigger.isUpdate){
            objTriggerHandler.onAfterUpdate(trigger.new , trigger.old);
        }
}
```

Handler class code that covers only AfterInsert handler:

```
public class TriggerHandler{
    List<DateTime> lstDateTime = new List<DateTime>();
    public void onAfterInsert(List<Task> lsttsk)
    {
     Set<Id> setId=new Set<Id>();
     for(Task objtask : lsttsk)
     {
         setId.add(objtask.WhatId);
     }
     List<Account> lstAccount=[Select Id,Recently_Added_Task_Date__c,(Select Id,LastModifiedDate FROM Tasks Order by LastModifiedDate desc Limit 1) From Account WHERE Id IN: setId];
       for(Account objAccount : lstAccount)
       {
           for(Task objtas : objAccount.Tasks)
           objAccount.Recently_Added_Task_Date__c = objtas.LastModifiedDate;

       }update lstAccount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to do the same as with your `onAfterInsert` method, but need to change your method to sort records to only get the tasks that have been updated.

If you make the assumption that all of the records in `trigger.new` have been updated (a good assumption to make), then you only need to pass `trigger.new` to your method and can use an identical or the same method as your `onAfterInsert`. Just change your trigger to only pass `trigger.new` to the `onAfterUpdate` method if you want to keep the methods separate. Your class would now look like:

```
public class TriggerHandler{
    List<DateTime> lstDateTime = new List<DateTime>();
    public void onAfterInsert(List<Task> lsttsk)
    {
     Set<Id> setId=new Set<Id>();
     for(Task objtask : lsttsk)
     {
         setId.add(objtask.WhatId);
     }
     List<Account> lstAccount=[Select Id,Recently_Added_Task_Date__c,(Select Id,LastModifiedDate FROM Tasks Order by LastModifiedDate desc Limit 1) From Account WHERE Id IN: setId];
       for(Account objAccount : lstAccount)
       {
           for(Task objtas : objAccount.Tasks)
           objAccount.Recently_Added_Task_Date__c = objtas.LastModifiedDate;

       }update lstAccount;
    }

    public void onAfterUpdate(List<Task> lsttsk)
    {
     Set<Id> setId=new Set<Id>();
     for(Task objtask : lsttsk)
     {
         setId.add(objtask.WhatId);
     }
     List<Account> lstAccount=[Select Id,Recently_Added_Task_Date__c,(Select Id,LastModifiedDate FROM Tasks Order by LastModifiedDate desc Limit 1) From Account WHERE Id IN: setId];
       for(Account objAccount : lstAccount)
       {
           for(Task objtas : objAccount.Tasks)
           objAccount.Recently_Added_Task_Date__c = objtas.LastModifiedDate;

       }update lstAccount;
    }

}
```

BTW, I'm not certain if `Recently_Added_Task_Date__c` also covers your "recently updated" or not, but have assumed it does in the code above. Adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to write this by using a shared method between the on AfterInsert and on AfterUpdate handlers (since the logic is invariant between the use cases).

Note also, that I avoid the query if the Tasks are unrelated to Accounts, and if related to an Account, `Task.AccountId` will tell you so (in lieu of testing `Task.whatId`.

Furthermore, no test of `aUpdList.size()` is required on the DML as SFDC will do nothing on DML events of empty lists.

All that said, there is a builtin field:  [Account.LastActvityDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm?search_text=user) that may serve your purposes without the trigger at all (depends on your business needs)

```
public class TaskTriggerHandler {

  public void onAfterUpdate(Task[] tList, Task[] tOldList) {
     updateAccountsWithLatestActivity(tList);
  }
  public void onAfterInsert(Task[] tList) {
     updateAccountsWithLatestActivity(tList);
  }

  private void updateAccountsWithLatestActivity(Task[] tList) {
    set<ID> aIdSet = new set<ID> (); 
    for (Task t: tList)
       aIdSet.addAll(t.accountId != null ? new List<ID> {t.accountId} : new List<ID>{};

    Account[] aUpdList = aIdSet.isEmpty() 
           ? new List<Account>()
           : [select id, 
                (select LastModifiedDate from Tasks order by LastModifiedDate desc limit 1) 
               from Account where id IN :aIdSet];

    for (Account a : aUpdList)
       a.Recently_Added_Task_Date__c = a.Tasks[0].lastModifiedDate;
    update aUpdList;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this a bit easier to follow, same code as cropredy's though:

```
private void updateAccounstWithLatestActivity(Task[] tList) {
    set<ID> aIdSet = new set<ID> ();        
    for (Task t: tList)
        if (t.accountId != null)
            aIdSet.add(t.accountId);

    if (aIdSet.size()==0)
       return; // nothing to do

    for (Account a : [select id, 
                (select LastModifiedDate from Tasks order by LastModifiedDate desc limit 1) 
               from Account where id IN :aIdSet])
        a.Recently_Added_Task_Date__c = a.Tasks[0].lastModifiedDate;

    update aUpdList;
 }
```